# How to load a JavaScript file and call a JS function in a react web app?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, use-effect, onload

I am calling a **JavaScript SDK** and invoking it's function in following fashion in my HTML code and it is working fine as expected.

Here is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>My Test App</title>

    <script src="scripts/abc.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/xyz.js" onload="initXYZ('Param1')"></script>
</head>


</html>
```

Now, I want to call this same **Javascript SDK from a react web page**. I want to **call the scripts and invoke the initXYZ('Param1') function**.

So far, I am able to load the SDK, but I am not sure how to call the function as i did above. Here is the code I wrote in react app.

```js
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from "react";
import "./App.css"

const App = () => {
  const instance = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const settingsTag = document.createElement("script");
    settingsTag.src = "scripts/abc.js";
    instance.current.appendChild(settingsTag);

    const websdkTag = document.createElement("script");
    websdkTag.src = "scripts/xyz.js";
    instance.current.appendChild(websdkTag);

    

  }, []);
  return (
    <>
    <h1>My React app</h1>
    <div ref={instance} >
    </>
  );
  
};
export default App;
```

Can you please help me to understand how to invoke the function in above code. Also is there a better way to what I did here?

Comment: I think you have to import as `type="module"`. Does this work?

Comment: Define the `initXYZ()` function on the `window` object. So `window.initXYZ = () => console.log('init');`

Comment: settingsTag.type= "module";

Comment: @celsiuss where should i call this line of code? Inside HTML?

Comment: @Rohit that entirely depends on your app and what you want to do in that function. Preferably not inside the html. Preferably in some init script you have that will be run before you load the external js libs.

Comment: @ru4ert but how do I call the function initXYZ('param1')

Comment: " I want to call the scripts" which script? At what point to you wish to call it? Do you want to call this inside the `useEffect`?  Do you just wish to call it when the page loads?

Comment: I just wish to call it when the page loads?

Comment: i want to call the function of the script on click of the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I do with my own SDK.

Simply creates as many classes as you have sections in your desired SDK.
Embed all those sub SDKs into an object SDK that you reference from your app.
See how it might look like:

Sdk.js

```
// From here, pretend the following is the content of your sdk.js

class SdkAbc {
  static shared // The singleton
  constructor() {

    // If already created, returned the singleton
    if (SdkAbc.shared) return SdkAbc.shared

    // Actually create the instance
    SdkAbc.shared = this

    // You might want to write your init code right below
    
  }

  version() { 
     return 1.3
  }
    
}

class SdkXyz {
   // Same as above
}

// You SDK singleton can host as many SDK sections as you need
const Sdk = {
   abc: new SdkAbc(),
   xyz: new SdkXyz(),
}

export default Sdk
```

App.js

```
    import React, {useEffect, useRef} from "react";
    import "./App.css"

import sdk from './sdk/sdk' // provided sdk.js is your sdk file located in /sdk folder



    const App = () => {
    
      return (
        <>
        <h1>My React app</h1>
        <div>Sdk Abc version: {Sdk.abc.version()} >
        </>
      );
      
    };
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [react-helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) to add any js file to page